# Display related DB values in Razor View: NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have 4 related tables: Project->ProjectDoc->Comment->CommentReply & Users
3 of those tables are related to Users. When I try to get the User.FirstName value, it gives me the exception indicating that:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

So first the User model.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CommentReply> CommentReply { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Project { get; set; }
}
```

Now the Project model.

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectDoc> ProjectDoc { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Now the Razor View. I've labeled the exceptions.

```
@Model.User.FirstName   //exception

@foreach (var doc in Model.ProjectDoc)
{
    @doc.DocTitle
    <br />  
       <div>
           @doc.Comment.Count() comments
       </div>
   foreach (var comment in doc.Comment)
   { 
       <div>
        @comment.CommentVote.Count() 
        votes
        @comment.UserID - user ID<br />

        @comment.User.FirstName  //exception
        @comment.Text
       </div>
       <br />
       foreach (var creply in comment.CommentReply)
       {

          @creply.User.FirstName   //exception
          <br />
          @creply.Text
          <br />
       }
   }
}
```

If I remove the User.FirstName lines then it works fine. What do I need to change to get the FirstName value? Do you need more information to help?

**UPDATE**: My controller, if it helps.

```
    // GET: /Projects/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
        if (project == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(project);
    }
```

I tried changing my controller to this as well, didn't work

```
      Project project = db.Projects
          .Include(i => i.User)
          .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProjectID == id);
```

**Update 2**: Fluent API Mapping Issues?

The UserID field has a value, however the User_UserID value is NULL, so I assume I am doing my fluent api mapping incorrectly (I don't want the User_UserID column).

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
      .HasMany(p => p.Project)
      .WithRequired()
      .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserID)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Is that causing the problem?

Comment: Based on the error message, the User is null. Is it possible that the userId in the CommentReply table can be null?

Comment: No, '@comment.UserID' works '@comment.User.FirstName' does not. The UserID values are all there is the tables, as is the User record with the associated ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to use lazy-loading of entities  ... in order to make it work, navigation properties must be marked as virtual, so EF can use a proxy class to load data when necessary.

In your model the `User` property in the `Project` class isn't marked as virtual, so lazy-loading wouldn't work.

You can either make the `User` property virtual or use the `Include` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) to load data without lazy-loading.

Comment: I edited so that the line 'public User User { get; set; }' in the Project class is now 'public virtual User User { get; set; }' then updated the database, the exception still occurs? I am using migrations and when I add a new migration it shows essentially no change happening though, so I'm not sure what the difference in the two is?

Comment: It's correct, making the `User` property virtual shouldn't change your database schema, it only changes the way how the EF handles the property - there is a nice tutorial on the topic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232

Comment: Are you sure, you have related user in your database? Do you use any configuration for your DbContext or do you rely on EF conventions?

Comment: I'm not sure. Just trying to learn .Net and MVC. I do have this in the Context class, maybe it's causing the problem? "modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(p => p.Project).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.UserID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);" trying to get around errors it was throwing when I seeded the database. As for having the value in the database, it's there.

Comment: Also, I tried the include method, see the original post for how I updated the controller.

Comment: So it looks like I have another problem I don't understand. There is a User_UserID field and a UserID field. I don't know what is causing the User_UserID to be created... is it the Fluent API mapping? I'm guessing that's my problem?

Comment: The call to `WithRequired()` tells EF that there isn't any navigation property on the other side (`Project` class) of the relationship, but you want `User` to be a navigation property. You should use `.WithRequired(c => c.User)`

Answer (score 0):

Just a caution on lazy loading... As far as I can tell, you are only getting the list of ProjectDoc from the database. Then you look through each ProjectDoc and for each doc, you are using the navigation properties (@doc.Comment) and then for each comment you go through the comment reply.

If I am not mistaking, each one of those calls is hitting the database. You might want to consider pulling all the data you will need in one query instead of hitting the db for each item.

Take a look at the [n+1 select problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem).

Comment: Yikes, so in the case where there are 10 ProjectDocs and 100 comments on each doc it's a crazy amount of hits just to load the initial information... Any chance you know any easy solution to this in .net? I read through some of the link you gave, but frankly I'm a little overwhelmed trying to move from basic php and mysql to .Net.